# Preload URL in webview in the next activity

Tags: android, webview, android-activity, cordova

I have 2 Activities. In the second Activity I have a WebView in which I load a local html page(from the assets folder). In the onCreate method I call webView.loadUrl(url). 

I need a slide in transition from the first Activity to the second. And this is where my problem comes in: The second activity slides in as it should, but it takes a moment to show the page in the WebView. So, basically, there's just a white empty screen that slides in.
I need the second Activity to load the html page before it slides in.

How do I do that?

Comment: How are you creating the second activity and when ?

Comment: I'm using an Intent to start the second activity when a button is clicked on the first activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to move the contents of your second activity (WebView etc) into a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and push it into the existing Activity. That way you could preload the WebView into the fragment before showing it.

Comment: I thought of this, but how do I handle the back from Fragment2 to Fragment1? Bare in mind that I will have multiple screens, not just 2.

Comment: From the docs, "The back stack allows the user to reverse a fragment transaction (navigate backwards), by pressing the Back button.".

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't really.

only one Activity is "active"(on the screen) at a time, because of this your SecondActivity cannot be doing anything while your FirstActivity is still visible.

You can achieve a similar effect as what you are after if you use only 1 Activity with 2 WebViews, one visible, and one hidden. You should be able to load a url in the second (hidden) webview while its hidden, and then make it visible and slide it in whenever you are ready.

Comment: This was an idea, but I need to do the same with more than 2 screens. And there's the issue of Back navigation.